# a4j:ajax with immediate="true"

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

**Version :**

JSF 2.0

Based on code listings given below , I have following questions :

1)In second case , I thought `bean.select` setter method won't get called , but it gets called. 
Why is that , even though `immediate="true"` skips process validations , update model vales and invoke applications phases and `bean.setSelect` will happen in 
update model values phase ?

2)Will validation for `h:selectBooleanCheckBox` will be skipped in second case , if there is any ?

3)The documentation for `a4j:ajax` says that with `immediate="true"` , listener or action will be called in Apply Request Values phase instead of 
invoke application. Then which phase setter method `#{bean.select}` is called ?

**Listing 1 :**

```
<h:form>

    <h:selectBooleanCheckBox value="#{bean.select}">
        <a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="formId">
                </a4j:ajax>             
    </h:selectBooleanCheckBox>

</h:form>
```

**Listing 2 :**

```
<h:form id="formId">

    <h:selectBooleanCheckBox value="#{bean.select}">
        <a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="formId" immediate="true">
                </a4j:ajax>             
    </h:selectBooleanCheckBox>
</h:form>
```